# Browser Crashes before Input is Entered

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a program in javascript that is supposed to be a fast paced typing challenge. The issue is that my script that's checking for input is crashing my browser before I can enter anything. I thought that it'd pause to wait for input but it seems like I might be wrong?

Here is the function that crashes my browser:

```
var level1 = function () {

var letter;
var ascii;
var ncorrect = 0;
var input = "0";
var timedout = false;

document.getElementById('prompt').text = "Level 1 : Type Here!" // this is supposed to change text on the page... It doesn't work but not that's not my question.

while (ncorrect < 26){

    timedout = false;
    setTimeout(timedout = true, 5000);
    ascii = Math.floor(Math.random() * 122) + 97;   // ASCII's of lower case letters
    letter = String.fromCharCode(ascii);
    document.getElementById('letter').text = letter;

    input = document.getElementById('keyinput');
    console.log(input);

    if(!timedout && input === letter) {
        clearTimeout();
        ncorrect++;
    }
    else {
        ncorrect = 0;
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

If it's not a simple fix...
What would be a better way of monitoring input and responding to a right answer?

Thanks, I know it's a little broad of a question but I'm struggling to figure out what I'm looking for.

Comment: get rid of the _while_, there's no reason for it and it causes your crash. you also need to pass setTimeout a program, not an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is already running an event loop in the background, so you don't need your own. This loop runs continuously and checks to see if any events have fired on any of the HTML DOM Elements. For example, if a button has been clicked, the event loop will pick up a click event for that element. You can add event handlers to the element, which are functions that fire when certain events occur to that element. What you want to do is set an event handler for the event that fires whenever the text in your input area (I'm assuming that the user is typing in an input or textarea tag) is fired.

For example, the following simple program will create a typing challenge 100 random characters long

```
var ncorrect = 0;
var timedout = false;
//select an empty paragraph to fill with text
var challengeText = document.getElementbyId("challengeText");
challengeText.innerHtml = "";
//Append 100 random characters to the paragraph
for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
     challengetText.innerHtml += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 122) + 97);
 }

 //Check the number of characters typed since the last the loop hit the element
 var lastCharsTyped = 0;
 var charsTyped = 0;

 //Grab the user input
 var input = document.getElementById("userInput")

 //Set the event handler to fire when the user presses a key (technically, when they lift their finger
 input.onkeyup = function(keyEvent){
     //Ugly ternary to deal with the fact that not all browsers use the same api. If you haven't seen this before it means if which is a key of keyEvent then keyCoe is event.which, otherwise it's event.keyCode
    var keyCode = ('which' in keyEvent) ? keyEvent.which : keyEvent.keyCode;
    //Check if the key pressed is equal to the character in the text to match at the same position
    if (keyCode === challengeText.innerHtml.charCodeAt(input.value.length)) { ncorrect ++} else {ncorrect = 0;}
 }
```

It won't handle deletes or shift very gracefully, but it should give you an idea of the direction to take.

As a stylistic note, its customary to declare and initialize your variables right before you use them, rather than at the start of your program.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helps. Yeah my variables are a left over habit from C in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout()` and pass in a function that checks the input after whichever time you specify. Here's one way to implement this:

```js
setTimeout( function () {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox'); 
    if (textbox.value !== 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.') { 
        alert('You didn\'t pass.'); 
    } else {
        alert('Congratulations!'); 
    }
}, 5000);
```

```html
Type in the phrase "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
<input type="textbox" id="textbox"></input>
```

`setTimeout` is passed a function expression that checks user input and spits out an alert based on their typing prowess. The second argument `5000` means the function passed into `setTimeout` will be called at the nearest opportunity after 5000 ms has passed.

Comment: I should be able to make this work for my code. Thanks! I'll accept this soon if nothing better comes up.